# C# 2005: Remove icon from the form's title bar

Tags: c#, forms, titlebar

A client has asked me to remove the icon from the form's title bar. As they don't want to display any icon. But this me guessing as when I click on the icon property you have to browse to some icon.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Set **ShowIcon** Property of the form to **False** to see if that's what your client wants.

Answer (score 10):

There are two ways.

First is to create an empty Icon file and then **Select Form -> Right Click -> Goto Properties -> Goto Icon -> Select your file.**

The other approach is to set **FormBorderStyle** of the form to **FormBorderStyle.SizableToolWindow** or **FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWind**

And one more way is to set **ShowIcon** property to be **false**.

Comment: +1 for your commitment. There is another way: close your eyes and the icon will be gone! ^^

Answer (score 4):

Set

`FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog`

Answer (score 2):

You can set ControlBox = false. However, that will remove not only the icon but also maximize and minimize buttons from the title bar.

Answer (score 2):

There appears to be an updated process. Following the steps in the selected answer doesn't direct me to an option to upload an icon. That option can be found on Microsoft's site: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-a-custom-title-or-icon-to-a-database-0e43e135-dd0d-4451-84ea-4f547e14480e

Answer (score 2):

You can also try this:

```
this.Icon = null;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Icon  >  False
```

This COULD be a good approach, but these are good too:

```
this.Icon = null;

//Or

FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog

//Or

Select Your Form -> Right-Click -> Properties -> Icon -> Select file
```

That's all I have for this, I hope this helps you.